# The html code I get from the requests module in Python is different than the source code of the same webpage I get from the browser

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

While using the `requests.get()` method in Python, the response object I get yields a different html code than the source code  I get from the browser(Chrome). This is making it difficult for me to parse the code using **BeautifulSoup** module.

Is there any solution to this? Am I making any mistake?

Below given is my python script. The source code of the web page I got from chrome has an **`a`** id inside of **`r`** class which has a href link. So I thought I would be getting a link. But it keeps returning an empty list.

```
import requests,bs4,webbrowser
res=requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=wind+river')
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
sel=soup.select('.r a')
sel[0].get('href')
```

Comment: Google will block you or they will send captcha

Comment: @bigbounty  Why is that?

Comment: That's how they have designed their website

Answer (score 0):

Google loads from JavaScripts so requests cant load results.

Try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4

import time
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=wind+river'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='c:/program/geckodriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
driver.page_source
soup= bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
driver.close()
sel=soup.select('.r a')
print(sel[0].get('href'))
```

prints:

```
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5362988/
```

**Note selenium**: You need [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and in this code geckodriver is set to be imported from `c:/program/geckodriver.exe`

Comment: Can this be done only with the requests and beautifulsoup module?The book I am using to learn python uses only these modules to parse google search results.

Comment: @KrishnaJS Nope.. The book maybe not newly released?

Comment: And by the way ,I get a different code than the source even whe parsing yahoo search pages

Comment: The book explains using Python3.4.

Comment: Add ```headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}``` and ```res=requests.get(url, headers=headers)``` to scrape some stuff from yahoo

Comment: How do i select a class and id in bs4 if the class has a space character in it?

Comment: The class has no spaces it is two classes. Replace the space with a dot. ```class1.class2```